Avoid instantiating multiple objects ReactJS + Vite
I'm building a sample ReactJS + Vite app implementing OAuth2/OIDC flows and DPoP using the oidc-client-ts library and from the documentation I see that to instantiate a UserManager object I'd have to do something along the lines of
import { UserManager } from 'oidc-client-ts';

const settings = {
    authority: 'https://demo.identityserver.io',
    client_id: 'interactive.public',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email api',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    dpop: {
        bind_authorization_code: true,
        store: new IndexedDbDPoPStore()
    }
};

const userManager = new UserManager(settings);

Problem is that every time a component needs to use the UserManager object a new IndexedDbDPoPStore is generated. This, plus the fact that i need to programmatically generate a Private/Public key pair to bind an access token to the public key, a new key pair is also generated along side the new store.
This leads to problems when someone refreshes the page on a component that needs to use the UserManager and a REST API call is made because the DPoPproof will be generated using the newly created private key and not the original one.
Is there a way to prevent UserManager from being created multiple times?
I was thinking about a global variable but I don't know if it is the correct solution.
Thanks

This is the workaround adopted to avoid creating a new key pair every time the page is reloaded and the component is rendered again.
Disclaimer: this works only because the oidc-client-ts library uses the values specified in the code ('oidc' and 'dpop'). Any change to them in a future release might lead to loss of functionality of the provided code. This also applies if the usage of IndexedDB to rely on Private/Public key storage is dropped.
const dbName = 'oidc'
const objectName = 'dpop'
const clientID = 'yourClientID'

async function checkIndexedDbDPoPStore() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = indexedDB.open(dbName);

        req.onsuccess = (event) => {
            const db = event.target.result;
            if (db.objectStoreNames.contains(objectName)) {
                const transaction = db.transaction([objectName], 'readonly');
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectName);
                const getRequest = objectStore.get(clientID);

                getRequest.onsuccess = () => {
                    if (getRequest.result) {
                        resolve(db);
                    } else {
                        db.close();
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                };

                getRequest.onerror = () => {
                    db.close();
                    reject('Error retrieving ' + clientID + ' from IndexedDB');
                };
            } else {
                db.close();
                resolve(null);
            }
        };

        req.onerror = () => {
            reject('Error opening IndexedDB');
        };

        req.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
            event.target.transaction.abort();
            resolve(null);
        };
    });
}

Is important to abort the transaction if the onupgradeneeded event occurs.
